# Compress a folder to .zip on scala

Tags: scala, zip, gzip

Please help me as much as possible to compress the entire folder with the contents in .zip or .gz on scala?

example
Path: C:\Users\Documents\temp (temp folder with contents)

after the path: C:\Users\Documents\temp.zip(.gz) or Path: C:\Users\Documents\temp\temp.zip(.gz)

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this kind of thing and I'm satisfied with [Apache Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html). Their examples helped enough to implement combination of `tar` and `gzip`. After you've tried to implement it with their examples you can come back to SO for further questions.

Comment: I tried the method, but there was an access error, it is written on the forum that this happens if you do not specify the file. The problem is that I need to archive exactly the folder with the contents without going through the internal files to reduce memory and time consumption, but I have not found such examples. Please show an example of archiving a directory with files, and not just files

Comment: It's not possible to just archive the folder with nested folders and files, you will need to iterate through the structure you want to archive, check whether it's file or directory and generate archive according to that. You will need to create right _TarArchiveEntry_ for each node of your structure like [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-tar-gz-in-java/). The solution you're looking for can be some kind of recursion. Also, feel free to update question with your examples that may not be working.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout : https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip

Pack a complete folder :

```scala
ZipUtil.pack(new File("C:\\somewhere\\folder"), new File("C:\\somewhere\\folder.zip"))
```

and there is `unpack`.